# I want to integrate zapier chatbot in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, chatbot, zapier

I am trying to integrate zapier chatbot in my flutter app but did not able to find any suitable solution can anyone help me in this regard?
here is the zapier link: [enter link description here](https://zapier.com/app/login?next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dinternal%2520internal%253Asession%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A//interfaces.zapier.com/api/auth/callback%26client_id%3DB1W0XVBkRq4O9BLNsbcQeTiqLANq9TAtqHZuPpLJ%26response_mode%3Dquery%26state%3DeyJyZXR1cm5UbyI6Ii9pbnRlcmZhY2VzL3BhZ2UvY2xucnpqbHZyMjg5MDUwb21jdWJuaXVtNGEiLCJub25jZSI6ImJmZmM4MTAzYjVmNjMyNWI0ZmNiYWExOWNhOWZjNjFmNjNmMGZmODllMDgzOGI4OWQ4NjljMTEyOTBlMzk2NzdmNTc3NzM1MWJmM2VkOWM1YTQ2Y2NjMTkwOWU3ZTczYzFmYzY0YjM3YTAxMTQyYzU3MTRlYzQyZWEyMTg5NWI4In0%253D)

Comment: I don't think that zapier has a flutter plugin implementation. You can use inappwebview to make it possible if they have provided it.

Comment: I am adding link in webview but it is not showing only loading is showing.

Comment: you can contact official support on this matter